# Bitmap instead of Drawable

Tags: java, android, bitmap, drawable

I'm trying to make a simple game (such as Arkanoid) on Android.

I used some elements from ping-pong-game pattern which I found on the internet.

So I was trying to change this class (`GameObject`) by using `Bitmap` instead of `Drawable`, but some problems appeared.

I have got some questions:

1. The `Rect` object which I've got here used like field with it own resolution so how can  make something like this using `Bitmap`?
2. Is something like `.getBounds()` exist for `Bitmap`?
3. Can I make animated objects (blinking, change colour and e.t.c) somehow with `Drawable` or `Bitmap` is better for animation?

Here's my code:

```
package project.java.game.objects;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;

public abstract class GameObject {

    // Directions
    public final static int DIR_LEFT = -1;
    public final static int DIR_RIGHT = 1;
    public final static int DIR_NONE = 0;
    public final static int DIR_UP = 1;
    public final static int DIR_DOWN = -1;


    /** Higer border of object */
    public int getTop() { return mPoint.y; }

    /** Lower border */
    public int getBottom() { return mPoint.y + mHeight; }

    /** Left border */
    public int getLeft() { return mPoint.x; }

    /** right border */
    public int getRight() { return mPoint.x + mWidth; }

    public int returnCenter(){ return mPoint.x + mWidth/2; }

    /** Central point */
    public Point getCenter() { return new Point(mPoint.x + mWidth / 2, mPoint.y + mHeight / 2); }

    /** Height of object */
    public int getHeight() { return mHeight; }

    /** Width */
    public int getWidth() { return mWidth; }

    /** @return Recatngle, which is limit objects */
    public Rect getRect() { 
        return mImage.getBounds(); 
    }

    /** for intersection */
    public static boolean intersects(GameObject obj1, GameObject obj2)
    {
        return Rect.intersects(obj1.getRect(), obj2.getRect());
    }


    /** for coordinates */
    protected Point mPoint;

    /** Height of image */
    protected int mHeight;

    /** Width */
    protected int mWidth;

    /** image */
    private Drawable mImage;

    /** speed */
    protected int mSpeed;

    /**Life level*/
    protected int mLifeLvl;

    /**
     * Constructor
     * @param image image which will use for object
     */
    public GameObject(Drawable image)
    {
        mImage = image;
        mPoint = new Point(0, 0);
        mWidth = image.getIntrinsicWidth();
        mHeight = image.getIntrinsicHeight();
    }

    /** point change position  */
    protected abstract void updatePoint();

    /** object change position */
    public void update()
    {
        updatePoint();
        mImage.setBounds(mPoint.x, mPoint.y, mPoint.x + mWidth, mPoint.y + mHeight);
    }

    /**to draw object */
    public void draw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        mImage.draw(canvas);
    }
    /** set Left bound */
    public void setLeft(int value) { mPoint.x = value; }

    /** set Right bound  */
    public void setRight(int value) { mPoint.x = value - mWidth; }

    /** set top bound */
    public void setTop(int value) { mPoint.y = value; }

    /** set Lower bound */
    public void setBottom(int value) { mPoint.y = value - mHeight; }

    /** center of object on OX */
    public void setCenterX(int value) { mPoint.x = value - mHeight / 2; }

    /** center of object on OY */
    public void setCenterY(int value) { mPoint.y = value - mWidth / 2; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get bitmap's dimension use the `getWidth()` and `getHeight()` methods.

```
Bitmap b = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), imageUri);
int width = b.getWidth();
int height = b.getHeight();
```

To create bitmap from a bitmap of desired dimension, use the `createScaledBitmap` method of the `Bitmap` class

```
Bitmap newBitmap  = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
```

You can use the Android `Animation` class to apply animation on bitmap through layout. Available in the `APIDemos` application. (ApiDemos->Views->Animation->3D Transition)

Comment: Oh and btw I don't understand how to check objects intersection. I used `Image.getBounds();` with `Rect` before but what should I do now?

Answer (score 1):

Oh few days ago I find srot of solution for objects intersetcion - methods here just an example depens on how you make your some object class

```
private boolean checkCollision(Someobject first, Someobject second) {
    boolean retValue = false;
    int width = first.getBitmap().getWidth();//get bitmap from ur object then get 
    int height = first.getBitmap().getHeight();//it size
    int firstXRangeStart = first.getCoordinates().getX();//get coordinates
    int firstXRangeEnd = firstXRangeStart + width;
    int firstYRangeStart = first.getCoordinates().getY();
    int firstYRangeEnd = firstYRangeStart + height;
    int secondXRangeStart = second.getCoordinates().getX();
    int secondXRangeEnd = secondXRangeStart + width;
    int secondYRangeStart = second.getCoordinates().getY();
    int secondYRangeEnd = secondYRangeStart + height;
    if ((secondXRangeStart >= firstXRangeStart && secondXRangeStart <= firstXRangeEnd)
        || (secondXRangeEnd >= firstXRangeStart && secondXRangeEnd <= firstXRangeEnd)) {
        if ((secondYRangeStart >= firstYRangeStart && secondYRangeStart <= firstYRangeEnd)
            || (secondYRangeEnd >= firstYRangeStart && secondYRangeEnd <= firstYRangeEnd)) {
            retValue = true;
        }
    }
    return retValue;
}Bitmap
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for [BitmapDrawable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html) I think.

Comment: oh thx I should try to look smth about it, but in JetBoy game example there are just Bitmaps everywhere so thats why i am interested in bitmap